# Telling git that the "older" version of file is actually "new"

Tags: git, branch

I submitted a PR but then decided to remove some files from it.  So I made a new branch "fluff", went back to the PR branch, and did a bunch of git checkout from master.  Git commit, git push, my PR is now smaller, all is well.

However, the "fluff" branch is now 1 commit **behind** the PR branch.  If I git pull from the PR branch, or from master after PR is merged, my changes will be reverted.

What is the best way to avoid it?  How do I tell git that "fluff" is **newer** than other branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... I think you should rewrite history of your PR to be a single commit and then set fluff changes from the squashed pr to be on top of the PR.... so:

```
git checkout pr
git reset --soft HEAD~2 # set branch pointer where we started the branch
git commit -m "this is my pr" # no more reversal in history
# now we can set fluff on top of it
git checkout fluff
git reset --soft pr # set fluff pointer to be on or, all changes between fluff and pr will be added to master
git commit -m "get all my changes to be ON TOP of pr, not in the middle"
```

This should suffice

Comment: I think this assumes my PR only consists of 2 commits.  But I get the idea.